# Loading background image for ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a bunch of ImageViews in a HorizontalScrollView.  While the image is being fetched I would like to display some sore of loading image inside the ImageView until the actual image is available. What/How can I set the ImageView so that it has a loading image?

EDIT: So what I am looking for is a placeholder image/animation to indicate the actual thumbnail image is loading

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just have some simple loading .png stored in your drawable folder. When you first create the ImageViews, do so with the loading image. Once the final image is finished downloading, simply replace it by setting imageView.setImage....

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `FrameLayout` that contains both your `ImageView` (initially `visibility="invisible"`) and an indeterminate `ProgressBar` that's visible. When you're done loading, simply hide the `ProgressBar` and show the `ImageView`. To make it fade in/out you can use animations.

```
progressView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_out));
imageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in));
```

Comment: I definitely agree with this way if you want the actual progress bar animation. If you want just a simple image, my way would be a bit cleaner (xml wise ;))

Comment: Yeah it's definitely cleaner! The only problem is I'm not sure if `ImageView`s can have moving images; like if you want a spinner or something. If you're fine with a static "Loading" image (design guidelines aside) then you might as well reuse that `ImageView`.